# Can't find ATK Package Driver after roll back

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, touchpad, asus-laptop

I am having problems with my ASUS Smart Gesture in Windows 10 like many other ASUS Laptop owners.

I rolled back the ATK Package drivers before trying a reinstall of first ATK then Smart Gesture and now I can't find the "Keyboard Device Filter" which ATK was the driver for. The only thing under "Keyboards" is now "PC/AT Enhanced PS/2 Keyboard (101/102-Key)". I don't think it was there before.

But ATK is still installed since I get the error message when trying to reinstall it.
Where can I now find the driver to uninstall it?

- ux303ln , windows 10 home, i7-4510U, 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ATK Package could be uninstalled from Uninstall Program in Control Panel.
After reinstall I still can't find it in Device Manager though, but it works for now.